# Why are app download and installed file sizes smaller for newer Apple devices in App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, compression, app-store, app-store-connect

In App Store Connect when viewing App Store File Sizes for my app, I noticed that the download and installed file sizes are **30% - 40% smaller for newer devices.**

Why might this be? The first thing that would come to mind is that it has something to do with the Apple A13 Bionic chip, but I can't imagine how hardware could affect these files sizes. I have enabled bitcode in my app, for what that's worth.

Here's are the file sizes for some of the older devices:
[image: Older Devices]

And here are the file sizes for the newer devices:
[image: Newer Devices]

Comment: With bitcode Apple is able to recompile your code and take advantage of optimizations that may not exist on other platforms. Likewise, with App Slicing it is able to remove unused assets or architectures that devices may not need.  The only way to really know for sure why it's different would be to pull the installed application off your phone and open it up to see what was actually delivered from the app store to your phone.